# Is it possible to define custom naming conventions for resharper?

Tags: resharper

I'm using Resharper (with the StyleCop plugin, although I don't think that's relevant to the question/answer) to enforce naming conventions amongst other things in our code base. Pretty much everywhere this works brilliantly, with one exception.

For test method names I prefer the following convention:

> ThingOrBehaviourUnderTest_Action_ExpectedOutcome

Currently this results in an inconsistent naming warning and to-date I've just ignored it (I know I can disable the warning in that file, but then it disables the warning for all any other naming inconsistencies). In the list of styles I can assign Resharper offers camel case, which would result in:

> ThingOrBehaviourUnderTestActionExpectedOutcome

or underscore separated words:

> Thing_or_behaviour_under_test_action_expected_outcome

Both are close to what I want, but not quite there. I guess I'm after a way of allowing underscores as valid characters in camel cased test method names, or a way of supporting a custom naming convention. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this question is pretty old, but ReSharper 7 now [finally supports the definition of extended naming rules](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html). Those make it possible to have separate name styles for test methods.

Answer (score 4):

The [AgentSmith plugin for ReSharper](http://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/) should meet your needs through its regex rule support.

Comment: OK, cool I'll look into that. If I can use it side-by-side with StyleCop for Resharper I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears to me that the latest version of Agent Smith (1.9.0.0-alpha) that is required to support the latest Resharper versions (8.1 to 8.3) no longer allows defining custom naming conventions as described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/agent-smith-for-resharper. I really wish Resharper would allow me to define my own naming styles as regular expressions. **If you use Resharper and want this feature, please make an account and vote on this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-384091.**